# Regex for extracting pattern(s) in between parenthesis including the parenthesis itself

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

I have string like below,

`xyz xyz xyz(1-833-BBY-OPEN) xyz xxxx xxx(1-833-BBY-TEST)`

From the above string I need to extract all the phone numbers by using a regex.

*Example*

The literal description of the regex is something like ... *start with `(1-` and ends with `)`*.

And the expected output was ...

`[(1-833-BBY-OPEN), (1-833-BBY-TEST)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regex explanation of ... [`/\(1-[^)]+\)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/JgN6vt/1)

1. `\(` ... match a single opening parentheses ... followed by ...
2. `1-` ... these two characters ... followed by ...
3. `[^)]+` ... at least one (or many) character(s) that is (are) not (each) a closing parentheses ... followed by ...
4. `\)` ... a closing parentheses.

```js
function fetchPhoneNumbers(str) {
  return str.match(/\(1-[^)]+\)/g);
}

const charSequence = '\
  xyz xyz xyz(1-833-BBY-OPEN) xyz xxxx xxx(1-833-BBY-TEST)\
  xyz xyz xyz(1-833-BBY-OPEN) xyz xxxx xxx(1-833-BBY-TEST)\
';

console.log('fetchPhoneNumbers(charSequence) : ', fetchPhoneNumbers(charSequence));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const string = "xyz xyz xyz(1-833-BBY-OPEN) xyz xxxx xxx(1-833-BBY-TEST)"
const regex = /\((1-[0-9A-Za-z-]+)\)/g
const numbers = []
let match
while ( match = regex.exec(string) ) {
    numbers.push(match[1])
}
console.log("numbers:", numbers)
// numbers: ["1-833-BBY-OPEN", "1-833-BBY-TEST"]
```

**Explanation of the regular expression**

```
/              // start regex
\(             // begin with an opening parenthesis (unescaped)
1-             // require the exact string "1-"
(...)          // capture string that matches expression in brackets
[0-9A-Za-z-]+  // match any letter, number or hyphen one or more times
\)             // end with a closing parenthesis
/g             // when regex is re-used, start from end of last match
```

**Note**
This does not ensure that the string captured between the parentheses is a valid phone number. It could be a string like `"1-this is-not-a-number"`.

[Test regex online](https://regex101.com/r/1VKgFR/2)